# How can I do [hard coded number].[function call] works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've created this prototype function to format a number to my currency location.

```
Number.prototype.toCurrency = function () {
    return Globalize.format(this*1, "c0");
};
```

What happens:

```
var number = 123;

var b = number.toCurrency();   // "R$ 123"
var b = number.toFixed(2);     // "123,00"
var b = number.toString();     // "123"

var c = 123.toCurrency()       // error unexpected token  
var c = 123.toFixed(2);        // error unexpected token  
var c = 123.toString()         // error unexpected token
```

There's a way to create a prototype function that works like `toString()` to hard coded numbers?

Comment: `123.toString()` shouldn't work. Are you sure you didn't make a copy-paste error here ?

Comment: @dystroy you're right.. i've corrected the typo

Comment: Would the OP consider defining these functions inside a helper object, instead of extending the prototype of a built-in type? Such extensions are problematic because they may clash with future language/runtime enhancements. Why not follow the example of `Math.abs` etc.? Define a `Formatting` object with all your helper functions in it.

Comment: I agree with @DanielEarwicker and most experienced JavaScript developers too. Here's the usual link to explain why : [Maintainable JavaScript: Don’t modify objects you don’t own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)

Comment: @DanielEarwicker guess this is the way to go. I wanted to keep main code too lean..

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo - a bonus of plain functions is that you could have an array `a` of numbers and turn it into an array of currency strings with `a.map(Formatting.toCurrency)` (though then you have to avoid adding an optional second parameter to `toCurrency`!)

Comment: @DanielEarwicker awesome! I didn't realize that.. I'm going to create my own singleton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`123.` is parsed as a number, hence the "unexpected token" error when it's immediately followed by a function name.

Change

```
var c = 123.toCurrency()
```

to

```
var c = 123..toCurrency()
```

or

```
var c = (123).toCurrency()
```

Note that you probably shouldn't have this problem, as it's more common to either use a variable for the number or directly use a string literal for the result of the function instead.

Comment: It works for toString() and toFixed(), but didn't work with my own prototype function

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsbin.com/EFExuNIN/1/). Are you sure you don't have a problem due to the typo (3 r) in toCurrency ?

Comment: In Chrome console: "Number.prototype.a = function () { return a*10; }; 2..a();" gives me "ReferenceError: a is not defined"

Comment: Well, is `a` defined before you use it in your function definition (`a*10`) ? Did you mean `this` instead ?